# Laravel join two tables for ruled out records

Tags: php, laravel, join

In Laravel, how can I reject a record in a query based on a value with one of the table with which this table has relations?

For example, I have the Products table and the Categories table. The Categories table has a one-to-many relationship, one category can have many products. The categories table are is_visible is_deleted. How to make inquiries on the Products table so that it rejects products that belong to the category that has and set fields is_visible = false or is_deleted = true ?

I tried something like this:

```
    $products = ProductTable::join('product_category_tables', 'product_category_tables.id', '=', 'product_tables.id')
        ->where('product_category_tables.is_visible', '=', true)
        ->where('product_category_tables.is_deleted', '=', false)
        ->where('product_tables.is_visible', '=', true)
        ->where('product_tables.is_deleted', '=', false)
        ->paginate(50);
```

But from this query I have only one record. I can't make this query on Category table becouse I want get only 25/50/100 products for paginate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Modal(Eloquent) and have defined the one to many relationship properly in both `Product` and `Category` Model. then you can achieve this by the following query:

```
$products = Product::where("is_visible", true)
                ->where("is_deleted", false)
                ->whereHas('category', function($categories){
                   $categories->where("is_visible", true)
                               ->where("is_deleted", false);
                })
                ->get();
```

In `Product` model you should have defined the relationship as bellow:

```
public function category()
{
    //From your mentioned query I am seeing that 
    //product table's id is actually categories table's id(which should not be like this though), 
    //so the relationship is
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id');
}
```